# Stub MST getter involving getRoot prior to afterCreate executing using Sinon in a Karma test environment

Tags: karma-runner, sinon, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I have a store of the form:

```
import { addDisposer, types, getRoot } from 'mobx-state-tree';
import { reaction } from 'mobx';

const MainMenuViewStore = types
  .model('MainMenuViewStore')
  .views((self) => ({
    get mainStore() {
      return getRoot(self);
    },

    get currentPageTitle() {
      return self.mainStore.currentPage.title;
    }
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    afterCreate() {
      const disposer = reaction(() => self.mainStore.currentPage, (currentPage) => {
        console.log('currentPage', currentPage);
      });
        
      addDisposer(self, disposer);
    },
  }));
```

and I wish to test it with a mocked implementation of `mainStore`

If I did not have a dependency on `mainStore` within `afterCreate` then I could potentially write:

```
  it.only('test MainMenuViewStore', () => {
    // NOTE: This throws due to attempted access of undefined mainStore
    const store = MainMenuViewStore.create();

    const mockMainStore = { currentPage: { title: 'Test Title' } };
    sinon.stub(store, 'mainStore').returns(mockMainStore);

    expect(mockMainStore.currentPageTitle).to.equal('Test Title');
  });
```

However, this is not viable because `mainStore` is depended upon during `afterCreate` which runs prior to `store` being returned via `create`

Additionally, MST does not implement a prototypical inheritance pattern. So, the following approach is not viable:

```
  it.only('test MainMenuViewStore', () => {
    const mockMainStore = { currentPage: { title: 'Test Title' } };
    
    // NOTE: this throws due to prototype being undefined
    sinon.stub(MainMenuViewStore.prototype, 'mainStore').returns(mockMainStore);

    const store = MainMenuViewStore.create();

    expect(mockMainStore.currentPageTitle).to.equal('Test Title');
  });
```

Additionally, I am not in an environment which allows for the use of Jest. If I were using Jest I would have alternatives that would be simple. For example, I could use `jest.mock` to stub the imported `getRoot` function rather than attempting to stub `mainStore`.

I want to confirm that the only viable approach for me to pursue is to introduce something like [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) to stub the module responsible for providing `getRoot`. I want to confirm that limitations of MST prevent Sinon from stubbing a getter prior to having an instance of a store.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can do the following to achieve what I want:

```
  import * as MST from 'mobx-state-tree';

  it.only('test MainMenuViewStore', () => {
    const mockMainStore = { currentPage: { title: 'Test Title' } };
    sinon.stub(MST, 'getRoot').returns(mockMainStore);
    
    const store = MainMenuViewStore.create();

    expect(mockMainStore.currentPageTitle).to.equal('Test Title');
  });
```